# Roslaunch using different port?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to use roslaunch to start nodes on 2 different machines. Apparently roslaunch will create it's own ssh connection - I have my network configured so that I use public / private keys for authentication, but I've set the ssh to be done over a different port. How would I configure my roslaunch file to do the same? (i.e. port 42 instead of 22)

Current file:

```
<launch>
  <machine name="bbb" address="bbb -p 4242" user="sparky"/>
  <machine name="spearmint" address="localhost" default="true" />
  ....
</launch>
```

Obviously that's the wrong syntax, but that's what I'm trying to achieve.

For reference, I can run `ssh sparky@bbb -p 4242` and connect just fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215369/roslaunch-using-different-port?/) by [Vasu Agrawal](https://answers.ros.org/users/22979/vasu-agrawal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is an example from ros-comm on how to do this, basically it is an undocumented parameter ssh-port you need to set on  like:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="machine-1" default="true" address="foo.bar.com" ros-root="/home/user/ros/ros/" user="whoami" ssh-port="4242" />
</launch>
```

see here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/89ca9a7bf288b09d033a1ab6966ef8cfe39e1002/tools/roslaunch/resources/example-ssh.launch#L10

---

Originally posted by [fbelmonteklein](https://answers.ros.org/users/32656/fbelmonteklein/) with karma: 140 on 2019-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-10**:
@fbelmonteklein: I've marked your answer as *the* answer and removed mine.